# Boostrap 4 collapse sidebar must be clicked twice

Tags: bootstrap-4, menu

I am trying to create a collapsable left menu, based on that nice example : [Codeply example](https://www.codeply.com/go/3e0RAjccRO/bootstrap-4-collapsing-sidebar-menu)

Here is the reduces code:

```
<div class="row" id="body-row">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-container" class="sidebar-expanded d-none d-md-block">
        <ul class="list-group">        <!-- Menu with submenu -->
            <a href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Dashboard</span>
                    <span class="submenu-icon ml-auto"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- Submenu content -->
            <div id='submenu1' class="collapse sidebar-submenu">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Chahgag</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Reports</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Tables</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#submenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Profile</span>
                    <span class="submenu-icon ml-auto"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- Submenu content -->
            <div id='submenu2' class="sidebar-submenu">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Settings</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white">
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Password</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </ul><!-- List Group END-->
    </div><!-- sidebar-container END -->
    <!-- MAIN -->
    <div class="col p-4">
        Content
    </div><!-- Main Col END -->
</div><!-- body-row END -->
```

CSS

```
/* Closed submenu icon */
#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"] .submenu-icon::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
/* Opened submenu icon */
#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] .submenu-icon::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Contrarily to the example, I'd like the have the menu opened on page load.

The problem is that if I remove "collapse" in sidebar-menu (which is done on submenu2), the submenu is opened but user must click twice to collapse it.

Here is a [reduced Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/EKGHZTCVjL) showing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "show" class instead of removing "collapse" class on submenus does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap 5, same situation to me,but i fix by adding `#` to data-bs-parent like following example(✔`#bar-topics` not ❌`bar-topics`)

```html
<ul class="nav flex-column " id="bar-topics">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#m1" href="basic.html"> basic</a>
        <ul id="m1" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#bar-topics" >
         ....
        </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```